# Issue with securing RTMP streams from Level3 CDN

Tags: php, hash, cdn, digest

I am currently dealing with securing rtmp streams from Level3 CDN.

The documentation can be found here: 
https://rapidshare.com/files/1450549534/Token_Components.html
(looks like you need to be logged in to view, therefore i re hosted on rapidshare. the original url is: 
https://mediaportal.level3.com/mediaWeb/help/Content/ServicesDocs-Streaming/StreamingTokenAuth/TokenComponents.htm )

Scoll down to *On Demand Streaming Input / Output Example ( For MP4 Files )*

I am trying to reproduce the example and to get the same url with the same values. I wrote a little function for that:

```
function flimmithash($file) {
    $streamer = 'pmsales';
    $host = 'pmsalesfs.fplive.net'; 
    $start_time = '20080101120000'; 
    $end_time = '20101231235900'; 
    $customer_secret = 'Secret'; // in the documentation there is also secret with a non capital s, i tried both

    $resouce_path = "/$streamer/$file";                                                     echo "resouce_path: $resouce_path <br>\n";
    $message = "$resouce_path?start_time=$start_time&end_time=$end_time#$customer_secret";  echo "message: $message <br>\n";
    $digest = md5($message);                                                                echo "digest: $digest <br>\n";
    $tokenvalue = "start_time=$start_time&end_time=$end_time&digest=$digest";               echo "tokenvalue: $tokenvalue <br>\n";
    $token = base64_encode($tokenvalue);                                                    echo "token: $token <br>\n";
    $url = "rtmp://$host/$streamer?token=".($token)."/mp4:$file";                           echo "url: $url <br>\n";        
    return $url;
}
echo "url: ".flimmithash('support/lvlt300kbps.mp4')."<br>\n";
```

I use the exact same values as in the example but just cannot get the same digest.

I used md5, because it matches the length. I also tried secret with capital and non capital s.

You can go to sample scripts here: https://rapidshare.com/files/2581196874/Appendix.html (Original: https://mediaportal.level3.com/mediaWeb/help/Content/ServicesDocs-Streaming/StreamingTokenAuth/Appendix-SampleScripts.htm )

But there is absolutely no md5 used, they use sha1. But sha1 is longer then the digest from the example.

Of course I tried to populate both versions with my values, but neither worked.

So my question is: Can anybody reproduce the example and/or tell me the digest or alter my function to work according to the example?

Comment: Both links to level3 fail, I assume you need to be logged in to see that content.

Comment: The links you've inserted are broken/incorrect/whatever. I just get to page stating "An unexpected error has occurred.".

Comment: If they use SHA-1, it's definitely not going to work with MD5.  They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: You could try all of [hash_algos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) with [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), maybe you're lucky. ;)

Comment: sorry did not notice that the links were not functional! i re-hosted the specific pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their example is incorrect. The digest they give is for the file `/support/lvlt300kbps.flv` and can easily be generated with md5 for that filename, using the lowercase `secret` as the shared secret. You can see it's identical to the digest given in the FLV example just above it in their documentation.

Comment: you are right! that means they dont include the streamer in the hash whcih makes sense. will try it out on monday!